# How to create a MySQL Query to get sales for each date of month (Like Calendar)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: **Product**, **Invoice** and **Invoice_Detail**
 [image]

I want to generate a monthly sales report for each date of a given month as shown in figure below.
[image]

I have tried many queries with different joins but I am not getting the desired output. How can I achieve the desired monthly sales report with a query as shown in figure 2?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select p.p_name,
       sum(case when day(i.i_date) = 1 then id.id_quantity else 0 end) as day_01,
       sum(case when day(i.i_date) = 1 then id.id_quantity else 0 end) as day_02,
       . . .  -- fill in for the rest of the days
       sum(case when day(i.i_date) = 1 then id.id_quantity else 0 end) as day_31
from invoice i join
     invoice_detail id
     on id.id_invoice = i.i_id
     product p
     on id.id_product = p.p_id
where i.i_date >= '2019-08-01' and
      i.i_date < '2019-09-01'
group by p.p_name;
```

The only real things to note is the filtering on the dates, so you have data for only one month and use of `day()` for the day of the month.